# Lightweight python to execuable?

Tags: python, exe, nuitka, lightweight-processes

I have been using `pyinstaller` as my method of turning a python file into an executable. However, the executable's size is over 6mb for even a small application such as printing `"hello world"`

I did some research and found out that there was a program called `nuitka` that compiles the file down to language C and does some optimizing. However, it turns out that `nuitka` still needs `libpython` and is therefore creates executables of large sizes.

So is there any program or compiler that can turn a python file into a lightweight executable?

Comment: What is your actual goal? Why do you need a tiny executable and you are not satisfied with the options you already have?

Comment: My goal is to distribute some exe files that I made to others, and it's not so helpful when a executable that just imports requests and calls a website weighs more than 40mb. Also, when I create a program that has to run on the background, it takes waaaay to much cpu power. (And it takes longer to start the program up then running a normal python file too, but I'm not sure if this is another problem)

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the choice of your programming language if you have such tight requirements.

Comment: And take months learning that language? No thanks.

Comment: Have you tried cython or jython?